# phpmyadmin crashing when running sql

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have about a million rows from Woocommerce sessions in my `wp_options` database. I am trying to run a query to delete these but it keeps crashing my site.

I am running this command:

```sql
DELETE FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '_wc_session_%' OR option_name LIKE '_wc_session_expires_%';
```

Thank!